# app crashes after accessing photo library

Tags: ios, xcode8, uiimagepickercontroller, photolibrary, info-plist

This is what i aded in the info plist

Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Value     :  deportes wants to access your photos
Key       :  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
Value     :  deportes wants to access your photos

This the code of the action sheet and after picking the image

```
@IBAction func didtapc(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let myactionsheet = UIAlertController(title : "profile picture",message:"select",preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)




    let viewpic = UIAlertAction(title:"view pic",style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in

        let imageview = sender.view as! UIImageView
        let newimageview = UIImageView(image: imageview.image)

        newimageview.frame = self.view.frame
        newimageview.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        newimageview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newimageview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissaction))

        newimageview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

        self.view.addSubview(newimageview)
    }



    let photogallery = UIAlertAction(title:"photos",style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in


        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum))
        {

            self.imagepicker.delegate = self

            self.imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum


            self.imagepicker.allowsEditing = true

            self.present(self.imagepicker , animated: true, completion: nil)

            self.present(self.imagepicker,animated:true,completion:nil)


        }

    }


        let camera = UIAlertAction(title:"camera",style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in
            if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera))
            {
                self.imagepicker.delegate = self

                self.imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                self.imagepicker.allowsEditing = true

                self.present(self.imagepicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
        myactionsheet.addAction(viewpic)
        myactionsheet.addAction(photogallery)
        myactionsheet.addAction(camera)
        myactionsheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil ))

        self.present(myactionsheet, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }






func dismissaction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}

func imagepickercontroller( picker : UIImagePickerController, didfinishpickingimage
    image:UIImage, editinginfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {


    setpc(imageView: self.pc, imageToset: image)


    if let imageData: Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.pc.image!)! {


        let  picref = datbasestorage.child("users/\(self.loggedinuser!.uid)/pc")


        let uploadtask = picref.put(imageData,metadata: nil)

        { metadata,error in

            if (error == nil)
            {
                let downloadurl = metadata!.downloadURL()
                self.databaseref.child("users").child(self.loggedinuser!.uid).child("pc").setValue(downloadurl!.absoluteString)
            }
            else
            {

                print(error?.localizedDescription)

            }

        }

    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: What is the crash description?

Comment: It is blank  it just gives me a thread 1 sigabrt error 16 main

Comment: In your code, where you check for source type availability, change the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType` to `.photoLibrary` if that’s where your app crashes.

Comment: I changed  savedphotosalbum to photo library  and this error appeared Application tried to present modally an active controller

Comment: thanks it worked there was an extra line , but the function image picker controller is not executed

Comment: That would execute after you pick an image from the picker.

Comment: i pick and nothing changes and nothing is in the firebase database

Comment: Alright seems you have not dismissed the picker after picking the image.Try adding picker.dismiss in the didFinishPicking method.

Comment: i added this as the first line picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) but nothing happened because i think the function is not entered i don't know why

Comment: Your method signature, looks like it’s wrong. Add an underscore and a space before the picker. Like this (_ picker : UIImagePickerController .........

Comment: I added it also did not work  and also changed it to didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo and also nothing changed ((

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller - pls use the method in the link for didfinish delegate.